# Windows 8.1 refuses to upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

I have an Acer Aspire 5750G that shipped with Windows 7 Home Premium.  I reserved my Windows 10 copy after installing all updates that were available, downloaded the ISO, burnt it on a DVD and upgraded to Windows 10 by running the setup on the DVD from within Windows 7, no issues.  Windows 10 up and running, all my applications still work.

AND THEN

My wife has an Acer Aspire E1 570 that shipped with Windows 8.  I followed the same route, installed all updates until there weren't any more, reserved a copy of Windows 10, proceeded to the DVD phase, and, the bugger keeps asking me for a serial key.  I don't have one.  The laptop doesn't even have a sticker with the serial for the Windows 8 that it came with.

Any suggestions on how I can get past this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a phone activation option? You may be able to solve this by talking to MS support.

Comment: So on the `Aspire E1 570` it is currently running `Windows 8.1 Update` correct?  The simplest solution is to allow the upgrade to happen through Windows Update.

Comment: @Ramhound that could take weeks. I am a very impatient person, being the reason I downloaded the ISO image in the first place. But that is my last resort.

Comment: @nallar I haven't tried that option yet. Maybe tonight when I get home and have the machine in front of me.

Comment: You say the laptop doesn't have a sticker, did you look under the battery?

Comment: @CharlieRB - Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 devices do not have COA stickers.  The most they will have is a sticker which indicates it came with Windows 8.x but that can be put on or removed by anyone if the device is used.

Comment: @CharlieRB that is a no, but Ramhound seems to have hit it on the nail.  Only a Windows 8 sticker, no key.

Comment: If you start the upgrade from DVD/USB, from within a running Win OS, when you get to the 'enter key' part, there should be an option to ***skip*** at the bottom. The rest will then proceed as normal & activation will happen automatically.

Comment: There is no skip option :-(  I have exhausted my library of options quite extensively before posing my question here.

Comment: Ramhound is the winner. I did not get my answer to why the dvd didn't work, but it eventually came through on Windows Update. Laptop now has Windows 10. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the folllowing command in cmd.exe?

```
wuauclt.exe /updatenow
```

This should start the windows 10 download in the Update-Application.
You can then use the upgrade option to get windows 10.

Comment: Let me see if I am understanding you...  The effect of running wuauclt.exe /updatenow would be to obtain the upgrade option that I have already used to reserve a copy of Windows 10 for this exact laptop?  Or is there some other upgrade option that society at large doesn't know about?

Comment: We understand you are unable to comment because you have not earned adequate reputation. Please refrain from using the answer are to ask questions for clarification.