# "Get Windows 10" app stuck at loading screen on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I want to upgrade windows 7 Home Premium to windows 10. The upgrade icon (GWX.exe) appears normally but when i open the app nothing appears in the window instead of the loading circle. It keeps rotating but the "reserve windows 10" thing doesn't appear. I can't find the solution anywhere on the internet.

Comment: If you reserved Windows 10 before July 29th, you can run the following commmand `wuauclt.exe /updatenow` in an elevated command prompt, to manually trigger the download process.  You can also download the .ISO and select the "Upgrade Now" option and bypass the Get Windows 10 application entirely.

Comment: I used the iso file. I suggest you write that as an answer so i can approve it. Thank you very much.

Comment: There are already multiple questions with that answer.  I prefer to keep my answers stuff that has not been answered several times already.

Comment: here are two possible duplicates [1](http://superuser.com/questions/950472/windows-8-1-refuses-to-upgrade-to-windows-10) and [2](http://superuser.com/questions/951130/windows-10-offline-upgrade/951184#951184)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply downloaded the official windows 10 iso file and upgraded my device. You can download it from here: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

Answer (score 1):

You can use The [Windows 10 Upgrade Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to upgrade to Windows 10, best part is, all you have to do is click `Upgrade this PC` and Windows will upgrade you. No hassle of knowing what to do with an ISO.

Otherwise, if you want an ISO, you can get it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). Just mount and run `setup.exe` and Windows will ask you what you want to do, and you're away.